# Uploading an image with Retrofit 2

Tags: android, image-uploading, retrofit2

I'm trying to convert some iOS code that I'm using to upload an image on an Android device using Retrofit 2.0. My attempt at this is failing and I don't know why. The server doesn't seem to get the picture.

Here is the working iOS code:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90);
// setting up the URL to post to
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/uploadPicture.php", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"serviceIPAddress"]];

// setting up the request object now
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

/*
 add some header info now
 we always need a boundary when we post a file
 also we need to set the content type

 You might want to generate a random boundary.. this is just the same
 as my output from wireshark on a valid html post
 */
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

/*
 now lets create the body of the post
 */
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", persistentID] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// now lets make the connection to the web
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This is the failing Android code:

```
@POST
Call<Void> uploadImage(@Url String url, @Body RequestBody imageFile);

private void uploadInventoryImage(InventoryItem item, Uri imageUri, final boolean isNewItem) {

    final File imageFile = new File(imageUri.getPath());
    final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyDir" + File.separator);
    final String imageName = item.getPersistentId() + ".jpg";
    final File renamedImageFile= new File(root, imageName);

    if (imageFile.renameTo(renamedImageFile)) {

        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        String uploadUrl = "http://" + settings.getString("serverPath", "") + "/mamobile/uploadPicture.php";

        RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), renamedImageFile);
        MultipartBuilder multipartBuilder = new MultipartBuilder("---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449");
        multipartBuilder.addFormDataPart("userfile", renamedImageFile.getName(), fileBody);
        RequestBody fileRequestBody = multipartBuilder.build();

        mApiClient.getInventoryService().uploadImage(uploadUrl, fileRequestBody).enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<Void> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                //upload image sucess
                if (isNewItem) {
                    mBus.post(new InventoryEditEvent.OnUpdateSuccess());
                } else {
                    mBus.post(new InventoryEditEvent.OnNewSuccess());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable error) {
                if (error != null && error.getMessage() != null) {
                    mBus.post(new InventoryEditEvent.OnUploadImageFailure(error.getMessage(), -1));
                } else {
                    mBus.post(new InventoryEditEvent.OnUploadImageFailure("Unknown Error", -1));
                }
            }
        });


    } else {
        //file name failed;
        mBus.post(new InventoryEditEvent.OnUploadImageFailure("Could not rename image", -1));
    }
}
```

The request comes back as successful but the server doesn't seem to get the image.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, try to change service method description to this

```
@Multipart
@POST
Call<Void> uploadImage(@Url String url, @Part("description") String description, @Part("myfile\"; filename=\"image.png\"") RequestBody imageFile);
```

`description` part is optional. Just heads up, you need to hard-code file name in a `@Part` annotation. Its kind of workaround to existing OkHttp bug which is default built-in retrofit2 http client.

For the profound documentation how to upload files using please read [this](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server).

Comment: I need to dynamically change the file name. If I can't do that, I might need to rewrite this part of my api :(